# How to load vim configuration of the current user automatically when using sudo

Tags: linux, vim, vim-plugin

For the sake of security, I'm going to try to use non-administrator account only as far as possible. But It seems there's a time when I have to access *root* such as checking `/var/log/secure` that normal accounts can't reach.

I came across an interesting post. It says I can save a file I edited in vim without the needed permissions, rather than opening vim as root by using `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`. But, I think that's not the solution I had in mind because it only works under certain circumstances; there are many files in `/var/log/` that a normal user don't have permission to read.

I was thinking: what if I make a script that opens vim the current user's vim configuration **including a bunch of plugins** automatically while using sudo.
But, I don't know how to do, and I'm not sure if this would cause a lot of security risks and even I'm doing right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too late, what you want to create exists already:

```
$ sudo -e filename
```

This makes a temporary copy of `filename`, edits it with `$EDITOR` *as the current user,* replaces the original file with the new one on write, and deletes the temporary file.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know there was `$EDITOR`. Feel ashamed that I didn't read documentations. I should've searched many times. I learned a lot from you. Really appreciate your help :)